# Primefaces show video generated in bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my application, I'd like to show a Youtube video with using the `<p:media>` component. The media component gets the video URL from a managed bean.

XHTML

```
<form>
    <p:media value="#{bean.printVideoLink()}"  width="240" height="160">
</form>
```

Managed Bean

```
public String printVideoLink() {
    return "https://www.youtube.com/v/Vg6P5nWIVjw";
}
```

But I'm getting an

> **IllegalArgumentException** Cannot resolve mediaplayer for media component 'j_idt15', cannot play source:https://www.youtube.com/v/Vg6P5nWIVjw`

Any idea how to solve this error or are there any other ways how to include videos on runtime to the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to provide the type of the player as an attribute for `<p:media>`

```
<p:media value="#{bean.printVideoLink()}" width="240" height="160" player="flash" />
```

Comment: Works fine with FF35, IE11 and Chrome39

Comment: @kocko You are one of the few people around with knowledge in both ADF and PrimeFaces. Would you be interested in making a comparison between two JSF implementations? (I know offtopic)

Comment: You need to add an extension for the media component to recognise what player to use.